# Windows cmd: piping the dir list output into find (or findstr) is not working

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, find, pipe

I need to do some very big Windows searches for some specific searchterms in th *contents* of all the files in a folder and all sub-folders. The GUI search facility is not finding all my tests, so I would like to try to use **find** via the cmd.

I can list all filenames in *raw data format* using:-

`dir /S /B`

I can successfully search for the searchterm in the*contents* of all files in a single folder using :-

`find "Searchterm" *.*`

But there are thousands of recursive sub-folders, so when I pipe the output from the dir listing to the find (and exclude the filename parameter):

`dir /S /B | find "Searchterm"`

I am getting no results.

Furthermore, I have also successfully sent all the *dir /B /S* filenames to a text file:-

`dir /S /B >> filenames.txt`

and using **type** to pipe the contents of each file from the list to the find :-

`type filenames.txt | find "Searchstring"`

This does not work either. What am I missing? Microsoft's documentation suggests exactly the same format in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find as I am trying.

Comment: `command | find "string"`: `find` searches for `string` in *the output of the command`. So in your commands, it searches `string` *in the file names*, **not** in the file's *contents*. Better switch to the more powerful `findstr` command: `findstr /s "string" *` where `/s` searches the contents of matching files in the folder tree. (`findstr /?` for more info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your question(s) should be clear by reading the output from `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /?` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>ed in a Command Prompt window.

I'd advise that you use the `/L`, literal, option for your initial code.

Direct results example:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /P /S "Searchstring" *
```

If you first send the filenames to a text file, e.g. `Dir /B /S /A:-D 2>NUL 1>"filenames.txt"`, you could use the following idea:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /F:"filenames.txt" /I /L /P "Searchstring"
```

Just be aware, in this case, that unless you include a path outside of the target tree when initially creating `filenames.txt`, it will include itself in its own content. That means your `FindStr` command will also pick up any matches in that file too.

Comment: This has solved my problem and provides exactly what I need. I also changed to a different WinPC and the robelms that I was having do not appear, so there must be something wrong with the virtual machine.